# calculate end date from start date and duration in jquery

Tags: jquery, date

I have a situation where I know the start date and the duration(1 year) of an event in days , how can i calculate the end date ? Thanks in advance.

I have tried this step, but the output is invalid date

```
    var date1 = new Date($('#startDate1').find('input').val());

    var yearLater=new Date(date1 + ((31557600 - 86400) * 1000));

    $('#endDate1').find('input').val(yearLater);
```

Comment: what is `(31557600 - 86400) * 1000`?

Comment: Do you want to change the year or to add 365 days?

Comment: That would be the number of milliseconds in 364.25 days.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I don't know, I only copy from other sources, I think it is a process of a year - 1 day in milisecond

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:
Add a method addDays to the `Date`

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};
```

Example:

```
d = new Date();

d = d.addDays(365);
```

**EDIT:**
This is an example from console:

> d = new Date()

```
< Tue Oct 07 2014 21:26:42 GMT-0700 (PDT)

> d.addDays(3)

< Fri Oct 10 2014 21:26:42 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: What is days @Sam Battat?

Comment: The number of days you want to add. This is after modifying the Date object and adding a method called 'addDays'

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it, but it won't work. This is because I am using bonitasoft and apply the javascript/jquery to calculate the end date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an year then

```
var date1 = new Date($('#startDate1').find('input').val());
var yearLater = new Date(date1);
yearLater.setYear(date1.getyear() + 1)
yearLater.setDate(date1.getDate() - 1)
$('#endDate1').find('input').val(yearLater);
```

Comment: Emm... I wanna to calculate the end date if I have the start date and the duration. For example the duration is one year and the start date is 1/1/2015. Hence, the output should be 31/12/2014, right? Can you help me on that. BTW, thanks for reply my question